# MySQL slpited string in condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql questy

```
SELECT Name,Email
FROM customer 
WHERE Email LIKE '%SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1)%' 
OR Email LIKE '%SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)%';
```

In the Name collonb I have names like "Gearge Martin" and i like to check if there is any similarity between the Names and Email addresses. But this query doesn't give any records back.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE Email LIKE CONCAT(...)`:

```
SELECT Name, Email
FROM customer 
WHERE Email LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1), '%') OR
      Email LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), '%');
```

You were trying to compare the `Email` field against the literal string `'SUBSTRING_INDEX(...'` which isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks this worked fine just needed to put the Email Like in the front

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the column `Name` in your query. Change it as follows:

```
SELECT Name,Email
FROM customer 
WHERE Email LIKE '%SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(' + Name + ', ' ', 1), ' ', -1)%' 
OR Email LIKE '%SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(' + Name + ', ' ', 2), ' ', -1)%';
```